# WordPress: the_terms() is not rendering my taxonomy links as expected, why?

Tags: wordpress, datatable, taxonomy-terms

I use a datatable in my WordPress plugin to display titles and taxonomies but I am not get it to work properly in the output.

This line:

```
$return .="<td>" . the_terms( $post->ID , 'authors', '', ', ' ) . "</td>";
```

Result:

```
<a href="www.example.com/author1/" rel="tag">Author 1</a>
<a href="www.example.com/author2/" rel="tag">Author 2</a>
```

and leaves the `<td></td><td></td>` empty.

I want this result:

```
<td>
    <a href="www.example.com/author1/" rel="tag">Author 1</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="www.example.com/author2/" rel="tag">Author 2</a>
</td>
```

Multiple authors should be seperated by: `,`

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/) function *echoes* the value right away which is why your post tags are being rendered outside of your `td` tags.

From the documentation:

> Displays the terms for a post in a list.

When you want to assign the returned value to a variable you want to use [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) instead, like so for example (untested but should get you on the right track):

```
$term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'authors' );
$term_links = array();

if ( $term_obj_list && ! is_wp_error( $term_obj_list ) ) :

    foreach( $term_obj_list as $term ):
        $term_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_attr( get_term_link( $term->slug, 'authors' ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    endforeach;

    $return .= "<td>" . join( ', ', $term_links ) . "</td>";

endif;
```